# MySQL After Update TRIGGER with IF Conditional Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I  need to create a trigger to update the data on another table when an update statement is made on the present table.

I have two tables, a book table, and a borrowed-book table. On the book table, I have an available copies column and on the borrowed-book table, I have a copy and book-status column.

So presently the trigger I am creating is meant to update the book table available-copies column by adding the values with the data on copies column after an update on the borrowed-book, if the book-status on the update is equal to 'returned'.

what do I do:

```
BEGIN
DEFAULT @status TEXT
SELECT new.status as status from borrowed_book where borrowed_ID=new.borrowed_ID
  if status=="returned"
      UPDATE books b
      set 
       b.availableCopies=b.availableCopies + New.copies where b.book_ID=new.book_ID
END
```

Comment: You need `;` between statements. You don't declare the type of `@` variables in MySQL. You need to use `INTO @status` not `AS status`.

Comment: Or `SELECT @status := new.status`

Comment: You can't `SELECT new.status`. I think you mean `SELECT @status := status`.

Comment: please if there is a need for me to explain better let me know

Comment: I posted an answer several minutes ago. Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a query to get the status, just use `new.status` in the `IF` statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER book_returned AFTER UPDATE ON borrowed_books
FOR EACH ROW
IF new.status = 'returned'
THEN
    UPDATE books b
    SET b.availableCopies=b.availableCopies + New.copies 
    WHERE b.book_ID=new.book_ID;
END IF;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: sir i got this error message
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF new.status = 'returned'
THEN
    UPDATE books b
    SET b.availableCopi...' at line 2

Comment: I forgot `ON EACH ROW`

Comment: okay sir I still got an error messege

Comment: Sorry, should be `FOR EACH ROW`

Comment: thanks a lot for your time but please I still got another error message
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON EACH ROW
IF new.status = 'returned'
THEN
    UPDATE books b
    SET b....' at line 2

Comment: Didn't you see my last edit? `ON EACH ROW` should be `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: I tried making that correct but it still did not create the trigger presently the error gotten was #1064- You have  an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDH server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 7

Comment: You need to use `DELIMITER` before using multi-statement commands like `CREATE TRIGGER` or `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: I really appreciate you support to help, it worked